# Will my c# 8.0 using declaration dispose my object correctly? When is it disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, c#-8.0

I'm calling the following method in a loop while it is true, which leads to automatic reconnection. Since I'm using the `using` keyword, does it dispose the ClientWebSocket on each `try/catch return false` or it only disposes it *if* it reaches the end of ConnectAsync?

```cs
private async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket(); // TODO: Check if it's actually disposed
    _clientWebSocket = clientWebSocket;

    try
    {
        await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(_url), cancellationToken);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        while (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            var receiveResult = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, cancellationToken);
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count);
            
            ...
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        if (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            await clientWebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "bye", CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: When does `clientWebSocket` go out of scope?

Comment: I'm more worried that you're disposing something that you've assigned to the field `_clientWebSocket`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`using var clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();` is just syntactical sugar, it's short hand for:

```cs
private async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using( var clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket())
    {
        _clientWebSocket = clientWebSocket;

        try
        {
            await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(_url), cancellationToken);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            while (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
                var receiveResult = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, cancellationToken);
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count);
                
                ...
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            if (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                await clientWebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "bye", CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

which is short hand for:

```cs
private async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
    try
    {
        _clientWebSocket = clientWebSocket;

        try
        {
            await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(_url), cancellationToken);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            while (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
                var receiveResult = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, cancellationToken);
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count);
                
                ...
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            if (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                await clientWebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "bye", CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
    finally
    {
        if (clientWebSocket != null) {
            ((IDisposable)clientWebSocket).Dispose();  
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's also worth [highlighting this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952992/is-using-disposing-the-instance-in-this-case/71953081#comment127143843_71952992):

> I'm more worried that you're disposing something that you've assigned
> to the field _clientWebSocket

`clientWebSocket` is going to get disposed, but because you assign `_clientWebSocket` to this (`_clientWebSocket = clientWebSocket;`), **the object that varibale is pointing at will get disposed as well**! They are the same thing. They reference each other. I'd imagine this is not what you want to happen here, but it's hard to tell from the code you've shared.

Answer (score 3):

> The using declaration calls the Dispose method on the object in the
> correct way when it goes out of scope.
> From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#remarks

So, in short. When the method returns it will dispose of the using declaration.

If you want to test this you can create a class that inherits `ClientWebSocket` and you can create your own dispose override that does some logging.

Comment: even if it returns "false" through the `catch`?

Comment: That includes the method returning because an exception occurred, etc. Note that this is control flow returning from the method -- because it's `async`, it'll actually return as soon as it hits the first `await`, but that's not what the `using` cares about

Comment: that is correct @nop